# MongoDb Hadoop connector using Pig support connection issue

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-pig

`ERROR 2118: Unable to connect to collection.Unable to connect to collection.`

My Pig Code:

```
REGISTER /home/auto/ykale/jars/mongo/mongo-hadoop-pig_cdh3u3-1.1.0.jar
REGISTER /home/auto/ykale/jars/mongo/mongo-hadoop-core_cdh3u3-1.1.0.jar
REGISTER /home/auto/ykale/jars/mongo/mongo-hadoop-streaming_cdh3u3-1.1.0.jar
REGISTER /home/auto/ykale/jars/mongo/com.mongodb_2.6.5.1.jar
--name1 = load 'mongodb://hfdvmprmongodb1.vm.itg.corp.us.shldcorp.com:27017/member_pricing.testData' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader;
name1 = load 'mongodb://ykale:newpassword4@hfdvmprmongodb1.vm.itg.corp.us.shldcorp.com:27017/member_pricing.testData' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader;           
STORE name1 into '/user/ykale/mongo_dump/file1';
```

---

When I use the other load command which is commented out in the above code, I get the output as follows, which assigns 0 map reduce jobs.

```
2013-12-11 05:16:24,769 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2013-12-11 05:16:24,769 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 0 map reduce job(s) failed!
2013-12-11 05:16:24,770 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
0.20.2-cdh3u3   0.8.1-cdh3u3    ykale   2013-12-11 05:16:22     2013-12-11 05:16:24     UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs

Input(s):

Output(s):

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
null


2013-12-11 05:16:24,770 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
```

I am executing the Pig script with `Dmongo.input.split.create_input_splits=false`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the error `Unable to connect to collection.` was given when running this pig script? Could you provide more logs related to the error? The mongo's log would be helpful as well.

Comment: When I use pig connector and run the above script where will the mongo logs generate ?

Comment: The mongo logs are on the machine running mongodb, which is specified when starting the mongodb process. It would be great if you could locate where in the stack the error arises.